# How to generate unrendered HTML elements on web page with Angular 2.1.1 like stackoverflow?

Tags: html, angular

**What I am trying to do:**

I am attempting to create a web page with Angular2 which shows HTML on the screen in much the same way many websites do such as stackoverflow, css-tricks, and and w3schools (to name a few).  I would like to be able to copy the code and paste it somewhere else after its shown on screen.

**What I know:**

I have come to realize that it will probably be necessary to convert all of my opening tags ( i.e., `<` ) to `&lt` and to convert all of my closing tags ( i.e., `>` ) to `&gt`, however I am still not sure what the best way to interpolate some variables into the template.

**For example, I have this in my template file:**

```
<div>{{myTitle}}</div>
<div><p>{{mySubTitle}}</p></div>
<div>
<ul>
<li>{{item1}}</li>
<li>{{item2}}</li>
<li>{{item3}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**What I want to see (and be able to copy) in the browser:**

```
<div>This is my title</div>
<div><p>This is my subtitle</p></div>
<div>
<ul>
<li>Apple</li>
<li>Orange</li>
<li>Durian</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Stack overflow makes this really easy and nice to accomplish by letting you highlight the code you want to display on screen and clicking the `{}` button in the editor.  However, when I try using the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags in my Angular2 app, I do not get the same result, I cannot see the actual HTML elements like `<div>` and `<li>`.

**Instead what I see is:**

```
{{myTitle}}
{{mySubTitle}}
{{item1}}
{{item2}}
{{item3}}
```

I have used *handlebarsjs* in the past and am familiar with that library but I was under the impression that using *Angular2* would eliminate the need for *handlebarsjs*.  Does anyone know how to accomplish what I am trying to do in *Angular2* without *handlebarsjs*?

Comment: Please check your browser console then you can realize your mistake . Because currently you aren't able to instantiate the angularJS .

Answer (score 1):

For `<` and `>` you'll probably need to use `&lt` and `&gt`.

For the braces in template expressions you may want to use ngNonBindable directive.

```
<div ngNonBindable> {{myTitle}} </div>
```

Comment: ngNonBindable is not what I am looking for, I need the HTML elements to be visible AND the interpolation to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` or `<code>` for HTML to become rendered verbatim.

```
<pre ngNonBindable>
  <div>{{'{{'}}myTitle{{'}}'}}</div>
  <div><p>{{'{{'}}mySubTitle{{'{{'}}</p></div>
  <div>
  <ul>
  <li>{{'{{'}}item1{{'{{'}}</li>
  <li>{{'{{'}}item2{{'{{'}}</li>
  <li>{{'{{'}}item3{{'{{'}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</pre>
```

You need to escape `{` and `}` (for example like shown above)

Comment: I used the <pre> tags and its working nicely so far, except, I want the interpolation to work, as well.  Any idea how I can get that done?  I dont want it to say the variable name `myTitle`, I want it to get the string value of `myTitle` which is "`This is my awesome title, this is fetched by my component from a database and needs to be inserted in between the <div> tags`".

Comment: You **do** want interpolation to work. Then just remove the `ngNonBindable`. I haven't used it myself but I'm sure it will just work. If you want bindings shown verbatim in HTML then escape `{}` it like shown in my answer.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what `ngNonBindable` exactly prevents. I think it's `[]` kind of bindings.